# Android Studio - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

i'am trying to use Android Studio on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) , but i get these results in terminal when i wanna create a new android project, android stuck on Loading components for "application name" :

```
Exception in thread "Performance watcher" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Performance watcher"
Exception in thread "AWT-XAWT" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "AWT-XAWT"
```

So far i add this line to /etc/environment

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m"
```

and this line to /etc/profile

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
```

and i have more than 1 GB free space in my memory , but still getting same "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" error !
so what can i do ?!

Comment: There's so much wrong with this. I can just manage with 4GB total ram and 20s% free at the start - it goes up to 80s% usage. Your app would have to stay so tiny if you manage to get AS running and java increases ram usage each time you build, so you would have to continually open and close AS to keep the system from choking.

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM do you have in your System?

As per documentation minimum requirement for Linux system is
`2 GB RAM minimum, 4 GB RAM recommended`

Here is [the link for reference](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure but you can try this...

```
<application
....
   android:largeHeap="true">
```